# "Across" vs. "over" as adverb

Tags: difference, prepositions

**Across** as adverb cited from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/across_1):

> **1** from one side to the other side
>
> It's too wide. We can't swim **across**.
>
> The yard measures about 50 feet **across**.
>
> **2** in a particular direction towards or at somebody/something
>
> When my name was called, he looked **across** at me.
>
> **3** **across from** opposite
>
> There's a school just **across from** our house.

I'm trying to rewrite them into:

> It's too wide. We can't swim **over**.
>
> The yard measures about 50 feet **over**.
>
> When my name was called, he looked **(over / away)** at me.
>
> There's a school just **over** our house.

Are these adapted sentences idiomatic? Any nuances between them and the original ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's too wide. We can't swim over.

That's sounds fine to me but as noted in the comments some people would prefer to see it written more explicitly as *We can't swim over **there*** where *there* means the other side of *it*.

---

> The yard measures about 50 feet over.

That is OK but sounds very old fashioned.

---

> When my name was called, he looked over at me.

That's fine for *over* but you'd need to use *looked away from me* for *away*.

---

> There's a school just over **from** our house.

Also fine as long as you remember to retain the *from* from the original.

Comment: Can I say "look away at somebody", meaning I change my line of view to look at somebody else?

Comment: @KinzleB Yes, you can. It's quite correct to say "He looked away at someone else" but it doesn't have the same meaning as "He looked across/over at me" - now he's not looking at you.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I'm not so fond of "It's too wide; we can't swim over." It's not wrong per se, but I can think of other ways to say it I'd like better, such as: _It's too wide; we can't swim over **there**,_ or, _It's too wide; we can't swim that far_.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, you could add _there_ at end no problem, for either _over_ or _across_, I didn't add it as it wasn't in the original and it's not really needed.

Comment: @Frank - Lots of ideas aren't in original posts because O.P.s don't know enough English to add them. I think a few extra possibilities are often very helpful for the learner.

Comment: Yes. That's very beneficial. ^_^ @J.R.

Comment: @J.R. You're right. It might sound better to me without the _there_, but that's just me. The fact it sounds better with the _there_ to you means that there is some choice in the matter and it does help to make that clearer; (so as not to imply any sort of 'rule').

Comment: @Frank - Just a note of clarification: the reason I don't like the bare _over_ is because I think _across_ is the better preposition to use when we are talking about the width of something and being able to swim that distance. If the sentence read, "It's too high; we can't jump over," then _over_ by itself would be fine; in the case of the river, I prefer, "It's too wide, we can't swim _across_." However, in the case of, "It's too wide, we can't swim over there," the word _over_ functions as an adverb, not a preposition.